# Get ERROR: kind server_data NIY

Tags: database, bash, postgresql

I wrote a bash script to curl an api, then insert the json data into a table.

```
    json= ${curl -s user username passwd "api url here")
    psql --user username pass -c "INSERT INTO testdb (kind, data)  VALUES  ('serve_data', '${json}');"
```

then it says ERROR:  kind server_data NIY

the columns for testdb are

```
        kind text
        data json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we did not define the function which is supposed to be called when kind is "server_data"